# How to update three similar fields on different tables with same data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models **Commuter** and **RideLaterRequest**

**RideLaterRequest** table looks as follows.

```
create_table "ride_later_requests", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "customer_name"
   t.string   "phone_number"
   t.string   "email"
end
```

These columns are getting created from a view file where user enters these details and get created by a controller action.

```
def complete_booking_request
   #create a record of name, phone_number,email on RideLaterRequest
end
```

**view**

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @ride_later_request ,url: bookings_complete_booking_request_path, id: "get_otp_form", method: :post, remote:true do |f| %>

      <%= f.text_field :customer_name, hide_label:true, placeholder: 'Name', class:'form-control'%>
      <%= f.email_field :email,hide_label:true, placeholder: 'Email', class:'form-control' %>
      <%= f.telephone_field :phone_number, hide_label:true, placeholder: 'Mobile', class:'form-control'%>
<%end%>
```

Now I have another model **Commuter** with similar fields.

```
 create_table "commuters", force: :cascade do |t|
         t.string   "phone_number"
         t.string   "first_name"
         t.string   "email"
  end
```

Currently there is no option to create a commuter data from template. The fields in both the tables are supposed to carry same data. Seems like earlier developer just generated the table and went off.  How can I can update the phone,email, name from the **RideLaterRequest** to **Commuter** table at the time of creation itself?

Comment: Please, tag Ruby too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use after_save callback to save Commuter data like these in RideLaterRequest model

```
    after_save { |ride_later_request_data|
      Commuter.create(
        phone_number: ride_later_request_data.phone_number,
        first_name: ride_later_request_data.customer_name,
        email: ride_later_request_data.email
      )
   }
```

Or you can crate a method like these

```
    after_save :save_commuter_data

    private

    def save_commuter_data
      Commuter.create( 
        phone_number: self.phone_number, 
        first_name: self.customer_name, 
        email: self.email 
      )
   end
```

Comment: In the **RideLaterRequest** model ?

Comment: Yes, @user3576036 as you are entering data in these model from view

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Active Record Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) like `after_save`/ `after_create`.

In model RideLaterRequest,

`after_save :copy_data_to_commuter`

`private`

`def copy_data_to_commuter
  Commuter.create( phone_number: self.phone_number, first_name: self.customer_name, email: self.email )
end`

Here `self.phone_number` gives the value from the object of `RideLaterRequest` class which is being saved. You can also use `phone_number` directly instead of `self.phone_number`